# How to Implement matSort in Angular 5 Material Table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VBgI1ejjZQ) tutorial and data is being rendered in table. Now I want to implement matSort functionality on table headers. Right now, I am getting data from a service through getUser() function as shown below.

```
getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
   return this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

Here user model is an interface as shown below

```
export interface User {
 name: string;
 email: string;
 phone: string;
 company: {
    name: string;
 }
}
```

I am using service function from component as shown below.

```
...
export class UsertableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.userService);
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
  sortData(event) {
    this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.userService);
  }
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.userService.getUser();
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

I have included all mat-sort-header and matSort directives in template. And I am using (matSortChange) event to trigger sortData() function in my component as shown below.

```
<div>
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="name" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.email}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Phone </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.phone}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Company </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.company.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Now the sortData function is being triggered when click on any table header and receiving sort direction and name of header in event param.

But don't know how to proceed further to sort data? May be I can use subscribe to get data in json, to sort and back in observable?

And also how to set default sort (asc) on name?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution in [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8227) link give by [jjorbas](https://github.com/jjorbas)
Needed to use MatTableDataSource like this

```
this.dataService.getReport().subscribe(results => {
if(!results)return;
this.ELEMENT_DATA = results;
this.displayedColumns = [.............];
this.tbDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
this.tbDataSource.sort = this.sort;
});
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

Comment: @R.Richards I didn't get this point in doc 'Provide the MatSort directive to the MatTableDataSource and it will automatically listen for sorting changes and change the order of data rendered by the table'. I am using [dataSource] rather than MatTableDataSource in template.

Comment: I see. I recently changed the application I am building to use `MatTableDataSource` rather than `DataSource`. I would recommend you do that too.

Comment: @R.Richards Can you please be more specific and tell where to add this in my code? I have imported it from angular material. Now the only place where I using DataSource is export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {  and if I change DataSource with MatTableDataSource, it gives an error.

Comment: Sure. Go to the link from my comment above, then scroll down a bit to where is says *Getting Started*. Click the view source link `<>` in the *Basic Table* bar above the sample. Then click the *TS* tab that shows. There is all the code you need. Never mind! I see you found something.